# Navigation fill 100% of container

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a responsive nav code that I have tweaked for my page. I'm looking to get the code to display the navigation to be full width and match the Call to Action button's width. The problem is the navigation buttons all have different length of texts but I still want it to span the entire div to match the others and give the smooth boxed design. I essentially want it to look like this on a desktop view: [image: this] I would also like it to stack like this on a mobile view. (Mobile view shouldn't need any tweaking cause it looks good for me, I just need the desktop to span the entire width of the black div below it.[image: mobile]

When I changed the width to the `#nav` it always knocks a button below.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhr2bkex/1/)**

```
#nav, #nav ul {
  display:block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left:1%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by giving your `#nav` a `display: flex;` and `width: 100%;`. Then, assign `flex-grow: 1;` to your `#nav > li` along with `text-align: center;`

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav > li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhr2bkex/3/)**

**Result**

[image]

***Note** Don't forget to give your `#nav` a `display: block;` in the media query so it will stack vertically on smaller screens.

Comment: the only bad thing about this option seems to be that I lose the mobile responsive. Even with my JQuery.

Comment: @Zachary Did you see the note at the bottom? Just make sure that you're setting your `#nav` back to `display: block;` in the media query. The Fiddle is updated to represent this.

Comment: Got it! Thank you. Is there any way to keep the small white gap in between the buttons?

Comment: You have to add "display: -webkit-flex;" for crossbrowsing compatibility. And "-webkit-flex-grow: 1" also

Comment: @Zachary, Not sure what you mean. I see spacing between the buttons just like in your example picture.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer worked perfectly once I updated my code!

Answer (score 0):

It would be less pain to achieve it with CSS media query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

that display two different element when on desktop view or mobile view. To achieve the items fill 100% width of it's parent, you could use `table`, `tr` and `td` to easily achieve it